# How to clean ghci command history?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskeline

I have read on a simmilar question that GHCI is written on haskeline lib but I must admit that that doesn't help me enough.

I tried

```
import System.Console.Haskeline.History
```

and calling the

```
emptyHistory
```

but I do not know to to reference to the current GHCI history.

My question is how to I empty my GHCI history?

Comment: There isn't a `:clear` command in GHCi. If you want to empty your previous GHCi history, you can simply delete ghci_history in your config files. The location of those files depends on the operating system. On Windows, it's in `%appdata%\ghc\ `.

Comment: `~/.ghc/ghci_history` on linux.

Comment: An how do I do it on windows?

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic `%APPDATA%\ghc\ghci_history` if anyone is wondering. (`~` usually means `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` for Windows users, but by convention many programs use `%APPDATA%` instead)